# How to clip or erase a csv file with a non-rectangular shapefile?

Tags: python, r, ogr2ogr

I can clip a csv file with a ogr2ogr having 4 extents of a rectangular polygon. Is it possible to clip a csv file with a non rectangular shapefile?

Comment: ogr2ogr -clipsrc <your shape file>... works well. I have used it on shapefiles and it is faster than Esri. Assuming of course your CSV file is feature data and not tabular data, have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22497541/ogr2ogr-or-arcpy-for-csv-to-shapefile about using csv in OGR.

Comment: What will be the command line syntax? lets say that I have abc.csv and xyz.shp file. The resultant csv file will be mno.csv. How to put everything in the  command line syntax? As  I said I can clip a csv file with 4 coordinates b this command line syntax. ogr2ogr -spat xmin ymin xmax ymax clipped.csv input.csv

Comment: First you need to create a VRT from the CSV use the link provided on syntax... then OGR2OGR -clipsrc xyz.shp mno.shp Your.vrt.. this produces a shapefile of points which the DBF can be converted to CSV (use Excel or similar)

Comment: How to create a .VRT for a CSV file?

Comment: http://www.gdal.org/drv_vrt.html with examples. You will have to make the VRT manually but it's not difficult.. a bit of XML then copy/paste enclosures and change the file names.

Comment: IS it possible for you to create one .vrt for this situation

Comment: I cannot, I do not know the path or name of the file you intend to include. Go to the XML template http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/data/ogrvrt.xsd copy it all and change the links and remove what you don't want then save as .vrt file (Notepad will do, but Notepad++ is better).

Answer (score 1):

> Starting with GDAL 2.1, it is possible to directly specify the potential names of the columns that can contain X/longitude and Y/latitude with the X_POSSIBLE_NAMES and Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES open option.

**Example 1** - Consider the following `CSV` file (`example1.csv`):

```
Latitude,Longitude,Name
48.1,0.25,"First point"
49.2,1.1,"Second point"
47.5,0.75,"Third point"
```

we can clip the `CSV` file in this way:

```
ogr2ogr -clipsrc clipper.shp clipped_example1.shp example1.csv -a_srs epsg:4326 -oo X_POSSIBLE_NAMES=Lon* -oo Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES=Lat* -oo KEEP_GEOM_COLUMNS=NO
```

**Example 2** - Consider the following `CSV` file (`example2.csv`):

```
id;wkt
1;POLYGON((180 90, -180 90, -180 -90, 180 -90, 180 90))
```

we can clip the `CSV` file in this way:

```
ogr2ogr -clipsrc clipper.shp clipped_example2.shp example2.csv -a_srs epsg:4326 -oo GEOM_POSSIBLE_NAMES=wkt -oo KEEP_GEOM_COLUMNS=NO
```